# how to insert image into textbox wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

My form in wpf has has to look like this:
[image]

I need to create a textbox that contains a button and an image. The idea of this is that when I click on the image the text entered is shown as bullets . How can I do this in wpf? I don't know what tools to use.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you post this as answer in order to be accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of it as creating a user control and adding a textbox and a button to it, not as adding a button to a textbox (and note you can have the button overlap the textbox to create a similar effect).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use it at just one place.. you can achieve this like below:

```
         <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <Button Margin="3" Grid.Column="1" Width="30">
                <Image Source="myImage.png"/>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a borderless TextBox, and a button (with the image) near it, and surround them both with a border, what will give you the look anf funcionality you want.